# Send raw data to USB parallel port after upgrading to 11.10

Tags: 11.10, usb, printing, devices

I have a laser cutter connected via a generic USB to parallel adapter.  The laser cutter speaks HPGL, as it happens, but since this is a laser cutter and not a plotter, I usually want to generate the HPGL myself, since I care about the ordering, speed, and direction of cuts and so on.

In previous versions of Ubuntu, I was able to print to the cutter by copying an HPGL file directly to the corresponding USB "lp" device.  For example:

```
cp foo.plt /dev/usblp1
```

Well, I just upgraded to Ubuntu 11.10 oneiric, and I can't find any "lp" devices in /dev anymore.  D'oh!

What's the preferred way to send raw data to a parallel port in Ubuntu?  I've tried System Settings > Printing > + Add, hoping that I might be able to associate my device with some kind of "raw printer" driver and print to it with a command like

```
lp -d LaserCutter foo.plt
```

But my USB to parallel adapter doesn't seem to show up in the list.  What I do see are my HP Color LaserJet, two USB-to-serial adapters, "Enter URI", and "Network Printer".

Meanwhile, over in /dev, I do see /dev/ttyUSB0 and /dev/ttyUSB1 devices for the 2 USB-to-serial adapters.  I don't see anything obvious corresponding to the HP printer (which was /dev/usblp0 prior to the upgrade), except for generic USB stuff.  For example, `sudo find /dev | grep lp` produces no output.  I do seem to be able to print to the HP printer just fine, though.  The printer setup GUI gives it a device URI starting with "hp:" which isn't much help for the parallel adapter.

The CUPS administrator's guide makes it sound like I might need to feed it a device URI of the form `parallel:/dev/SOMETHING`, but of course if I had a `/dev/SOMETHING` I'd probably just go on writing to it directly.

Here's what `dmesg` says after I disconnect and reconnect the device from the USB port:

```
[  924.722906] usb 1-1.1.4: USB disconnect, device number 7
[  959.993002] usb 1-1.1.4: new full speed USB device number 8 using ehci_hcd
```

And here's how it shows up in lsusb -v:

```
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 1a86:7584 QinHeng Electronics CH340S
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               1.10
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0         8
  idVendor           0x1a86 QinHeng Electronics
  idProduct          0x7584 CH340S
  bcdDevice            2.52
  iManufacturer           0 
  iProduct                2 USB2.0-Print 
  iSerial                 0 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           32
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower               96mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass         7 Printer
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Printer
      bInterfaceProtocol      2 Bidirectional
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0020  1x 32 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x02  EP 2 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0020  1x 32 bytes
        bInterval               0
Device Status:     0x0000
  (Bus Powered)
```

Comment: does anything in post #2 here help you?  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cups/+bug/842823

Comment: Bug 842823 comment #2 seems to be suggesting that I try to use the GUI to auto-detect the device URI.  Like I said in the original question, this particular device doesn't seem to be showing up in the list of detected devices, though other devices do.  Comment #1 and the link to bug 872711 are interesting, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `/dev/usb/lpX` device files you are looking for are provided by the `usblp` driver.  It seems in Ubuntu 11.10 though, that this driver has been blacklisted.  See the `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-cups-usblp.conf` file:

```
# cups talks to the raw USB devices, so we need to blacklist usblp to avoid
# grabbing them
blacklist usblp
```

If you want to send data directly to the device still, you can temporarily load the driver with `modprobe usblp` (the blacklist only prevents the driver from being automatically loaded).  Once you are done, you can unload it with `modprobe -r usblp`.

Comment: It works!  The comment you quoted made me think that I might be unable to print to the HP printer via CUPS while the module was loaded, but actually that doesn't seem to be a problem.  Fantastic!