# Printer's /dev/usb/lpx file disappears on ubuntu mate 20.04

Tags: 20.04, usb, printing, ubuntu-mate

On ubuntu mate 18.04 I used to send data in hexadecimal representation into a usb thermal printer with this command:

`cat cmds.txt > /dev/usb/lpx`

I upgraded to ubuntu mate 20.04 and realized, that the lpx file (belonging to the printer) does not appear in the /dev/usb folder, like on ubuntu mate 18.04. I have googled a little bit and found, that

`dmesg | grep usblp`

command should provide some useful information about connection of the printer. I am not skilled at this area, therefore I do not use proper terms at this point.

With its usage I realized, that: On Ubuntu 20.04 the output is :

```
$ dmesg | grep usblp
[   17.634888] usblp 3-3:1.0: usblp1: USB Bidirectional printer dev 3 if 0 alt 0 proto 2 vid 0x04F9 pid 0x209D
[   17.634950] usbcore: registered new interface driver usblp
[   35.318303] usblp1: removed
```

while on Ubuntu 18.04 the log does not end with **removed** keyword and the lpx file shows in the expected path. The printer shows in output of lsusb on both systems:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 04f9:209d Brother Industries, Ltd QL-820NWB P-touch Label Printer
```

I susspect that on ubuntu 20.04 there is some process removing the **usblp**. [Since the  usblp should be responsible for creation of lpx files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80879/send-raw-data-to-usb-parallel-port-after-upgrading-to-11-10), they do not show up.

My question is, how to get usblp working to show lpx files on ubuntu mate 20.04?

Thank you.

EDIT 1:

The output of command `sudo journalctl  --since="-5 minutes"` related to the printer is following:

```
říj 31 20:50:53 dalibor-HP-EliteBook-8470p kernel: usb 1-1.2.1: USB disconnect, device number 8
říj 31 20:50:54 dalibor-HP-EliteBook-8470p kernel: usb 1-1.2.4: USB disconnect, device number 7
říj 31 20:50:58 dalibor-HP-EliteBook-8470p kernel: usb 1-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 6
říj 31 20:51:11 dalibor-HP-EliteBook-8470p kernel: usb 1-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 9 using ehci-pci
říj 31 20:51:11 dalibor-HP-EliteBook-8470p kernel: usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=04f9, idProduct=209d, bcdDevice= 1.00
říj 31 20:51:11 dalibor-HP-EliteBook-8470p kernel: usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
říj 31 20:51:11 dalibor-HP-EliteBook-8470p kernel: usb 1-1.2: Product: QL-820NWB
říj 31 20:51:11 dalibor-HP-EliteBook-8470p kernel: usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: Brother
říj 31 20:51:11 dalibor-HP-EliteBook-8470p kernel: usb 1-1.2: SerialNumber: 000M0Z803274
říj 31 20:51:11 dalibor-HP-EliteBook-8470p kernel: usblp 1-1.2:1.0: usblp1: USB Bidirectional printer dev 9 if 0 alt 0 proto 2 vid 0x04F9 pid 0x209D
říj 31 20:51:12 dalibor-HP-EliteBook-8470p systemd[1]: Starting Daemon to make IPP-over-USB printers available as network printers (001:009)...
říj 31 20:51:12 dalibor-HP-EliteBook-8470p kernel: usblp1: removed
říj 31 20:51:13 dalibor-HP-EliteBook-8470p kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1635709872.880:52): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="ippusbxd" name="/etc/nsswitch.conf" pid=68483 comm="ippusbxd" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
říj 31 20:51:13 dalibor-HP-EliteBook-8470p kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1635709872.900:53): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="ippusbxd" name="/etc/nsswitch.conf" pid=68483 comm="ippusbxd" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
říj 31 20:51:13 dalibor-HP-EliteBook-8470p kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1635709872.940:54): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="ippusbxd" name="/etc/passwd" pid=68483 comm="ippusbxd" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
říj 31 20:51:13 dalibor-HP-EliteBook-8470p kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1635709872.940:55): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="ippusbxd" name="/etc/passwd" pid=68483 comm="ippusbxd" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
říj 31 20:51:13 dalibor-HP-EliteBook-8470p kernel: TCP: request_sock_TCP: Possible SYN flooding on port 60000. Sending cookies.  Check SNMP counters.
říj 31 20:51:13 dalibor-HP-EliteBook-8470p kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1635709873.044:56): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="ippusbxd" name="/etc/passwd" pid=68483 comm="ippusbxd" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
říj 31 20:51:13 dalibor-HP-EliteBook-8470p kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1635709873.044:57): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="ippusbxd" name="/etc/passwd" pid=68483 comm="ippusbxd" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
říj 31 20:51:12 dalibor-HP-EliteBook-8470p audit[68483]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="ippusbxd" name="/etc/nsswitch.conf" pid=68483 comm="ippusbxd" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
říj 31 20:51:12 dalibor-HP-EliteBook-8470p audit[68483]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="ippusbxd" name="/etc/nsswitch.conf" pid=68483 comm="ippusbxd" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
říj 31 20:51:12 dalibor-HP-EliteBook-8470p audit[68483]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="ippusbxd" name="/etc/passwd" pid=68483 comm="ippusbxd" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
říj 31 20:51:12 dalibor-HP-EliteBook-8470p audit[68483]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="ippusbxd" name="/etc/passwd" pid=68483 comm="ippusbxd" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
říj 31 20:51:13 dalibor-HP-EliteBook-8470p audit[68483]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="ippusbxd" name="/etc/passwd" pid=68483 comm="ippusbxd" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
říj 31 20:51:13 dalibor-HP-EliteBook-8470p audit[68483]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="ippusbxd" name="/etc/passwd" pid=68483 comm="ippusbxd" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
říj 31 20:51:12 dalibor-HP-EliteBook-8470p systemd[1]: Started Daemon to make IPP-over-USB printers available as network printers (001:009).
říj 31 20:51:18 dalibor-HP-EliteBook-8470p ippusbxd[68483]: <-1643116800>Error: poll returned an unexpected event
říj 31 20:51:28 dalibor-HP-EliteBook-8470p sudo[68511]:  dalibor : TTY=pts/2 ; PWD=/home/dalibor ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/journalctl --since=-5 minutes
```

Comment: Page through the logs with `sudo journalctl -b 0` to see how system startup detects the thermal printer, OR disconnect/reconnect the thermal printer and `sudo journalctl  --since="-5 minutes"` to see the same. OR disconnect, `ls -l /dev >disconnect.tmp`, reconnect, wait several seconds, `ls -l /dev >connect.tmp; diff {dis,}connect.tmp`.

Comment: @waltinator - Thank you for you reply. I have attached the output to EDIT 1 of my post. Though, it does not make too much sense to me. Any other help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the debugging procedure for USB printers on UBUNTU webpages https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingPrintingProblems, the command:

`$ tail -f /var/log/syslog`

provides an information, where the problem with proper initilaization of a USB printer lies. When the printer is plugged back into USB port, it followed that, there is an unexpected event emitted by **ippusbxd**:

`ippusbxd: <1468000000>Error: poll returned an unexpected event`

This can be seen as well from log in EDIT 1 of the QUESTION.

[Similar problems with non-working USB printers have been reported on UBUNUTU 20.04](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/printing-woes-with-20-04-finally-solved-usb-cable-connected-printer/23498).

[A similar bug has been reported officially](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ippusbxd/+bug/1877095).
Worth to say, that ippusbxd crashes after its each start in my case.

[Fortunately, the community managed to get a solution of this problem:](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/printing-woes-with-20-04-finally-solved-usb-cable-connected-printer/23498)

> Yes, CUPS wants to deprecate drivers and go all IPP with printers; however, that part of Ubuntu seems to be broken when there is a simple printer plugged in to a simple USB port.

> I totally removed ippusbxd

[In my case, by using the command:](https://installlion.com/ubuntu/xenial/main/i/ippusbxd/uninstall/index.html)

`sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove ippusbxd`

the issue has been solved. The files lpx appeared in the /dev/usb/ directory again.

[Some functionality can be lost by removing of the **ippusbxd** package](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1313149/printer-problem-ubuntu-20-04-localhost-not-available-remove-ippusbxd). But in my case, I do not observe any strange behavior of the OS. [Together with installed driver, I am able to print with my thermal printer again with command:](https://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadend.aspx?c=cz&lang=cs&prod=lpql820nwbeuk&os=130&dlid=dlfp100345_000&flang=178&type3=10309&dlang=true).

`cat textfile | lp -d QL820NWB`